# How can I retrieve specific information from my sql query based on what information is filled in the HTML form fields?

Tags: php

I am brand new to PHP and everything else, so please try to keep any response as simple as possible. Thank you. I just can't figure out how to only get the information from the field that is filled in. When I do my search, it brings up the empty fields as well. I need just the information in the HTML form to be found. For example, if I put in a project code, I need all information that pertains to that code. Or if I put in a specific budget, I need everything that has that budget. I hope this makes sense...I'm such a rookie, I don't even know how to word the question!!!! I have tried using !is_null, (isset), !empty but none of them seem to work.

```
<?php

include 'connect.php';


// Get values from form 
$p_code=$_GET['projectcode'];
$p_name=$_GET['projectname'];
$budget=$_GET['budget'];
$s_date=$_GET['startdate'];
$e_date=$_GET['enddate'];
$c_year=$_GET['cyear'];
$c_qtr=$_GET['cqtr'];
$c_grp=$_GET['cgrp'];
$sponsor=$_GET['sponsor'];
$client=$_GET['client'];
$p_lead=$_GET['projectlead'];
$orig_hrs=$_GET['originalhrs'];
$risk_per=$_GET['riskpercent'];
$notes=$_GET['notes'];

if ($db_found) {



$SQL = "SELECT * FROM minimodtable 
WHERE projectcode='$p_code' 
OR projectname='$p_name'   
OR budget='$budget' 
OR startdate='$s_date' 
OR enddate='$e_date' 
OR cyear='$c_year' 
OR cqtr='$c_qtr' 
OR cgrp='$c_grp' 
OR sponsor='$sponsor' 
OR client='$client' 
OR projectlead='$p_lead' 
OR originalhrs='$orig_hrs' 
OR riskpercent='$risk_per' 
OR notes='$notes'";

$result = mysqli_query($connect, $SQL);

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Project Code</th>
<th>Project Name</th>
<th>Budget</th>
<th>Start Date</th>
<th>End Date</th>
<th>Year</th>
<th>Quarter</th>
<th>Group</th>
<th>Sponsor</th>
<th>Client</th>
<th>Project Lead</th>
<th>Original Hours</th>
<th>Risk Percent</th>
<th>Notes</th>
</tr>";


while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH)) {


echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['projectcode'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['projectname'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['budget'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['startdate'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['enddate'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['cyear'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['cqtr'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['cgrp'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['sponsor'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['client'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['projectlead'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['originalhrs'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['riskpercent'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['notes'] . "</td>";

}


echo "</table>";



}

mysqli_close($connect);



?>
```

Comment: Stackoverflow(SO), is not the place to learn about the 'basics' of HTML Forms, SQL and PHP programming and how they link together. I suggest a 'google' search of something like': 'php sql forms tutorial'. There will be useful articles for you to go with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've made a good first try there. This method should save you having to repeat yourself so much, though. You were correct to start looking at `isset` - the issue is that you need to dynamically build up your SQL query.

In fact, you'll probably want to change the glue in the `implode()` function from 'OR' to 'AND' - that way, you can find things that are a specific budget AND that pertain to a certain code.

I've switched it to `AND` for now - but feel free to switch it back to `OR` - as per your example.

```
<?php

// All possible parameters
$params = array(
    'projectcode',
    'projectname',
    'budget',
    'startdate',
    'enddate',
    'cyear',
    'cqtr',
    'cgrp',
    'sponsor',
    'client',
    'projectlead',
    'originalhrs',
    'riskpercent',
    'notes'
);

$wheres = array();
foreach ($params as $param) {

    // Is the param set?
    // If so, let's add it to our list of WHERE clauses
    if (isset($_GET[$param])) {
        $wheres[] = sprintf("%s = '%s'", $param, mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_GET[$param]));
    }
}

if ($db_found) {

    // Now let's make the SQL.
    $SQL = 'SELECT * FROM minimodtable';

    // We only want to add the WHERE clause if we had some parameters passed
    if (count($wheres) > 0) {
        $SQL .= ' WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $wheres);
    }

    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $SQL);

    echo "<table border='1'>
    <tr>
    <th>Project Code</th>
    <th>Project Name</th>
    <th>Budget</th>
    <th>Start Date</th>
    <th>End Date</th>
    <th>Year</th>
    <th>Quarter</th>
    <th>Group</th>
    <th>Sponsor</th>
    <th>Client</th>
    <th>Project Lead</th>
    <th>Original Hours</th>
    <th>Risk Percent</th>
    <th>Notes</th>
    </tr>";

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH)) {

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['projectcode'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['projectname'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['budget'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['startdate'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['enddate'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['cyear'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['cqtr'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['cgrp'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['sponsor'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['client'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['projectlead'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['originalhrs'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['riskpercent'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['notes'] . "</td>";

    }

    echo "</table>";
}

mysqli_close($connect);
```

Comment: Hi, and thank you for the response. I tried running your code (and while I don't understand most of it, i will definitely spend some time trying to figure it out) and here is the error that came up...Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in /home/a4169484/public_html/minimod/retrieve1.php on line 30

Comment: My mistake, I didn't test it. Try it now, I have fixed the problem.

Comment: No error now, but unfortunately no data either. It's just coming up blank. The form headings are there, but no information below it. I switched the AND to OR but unfortunately my original problem is back where the empty fields are being called as well.

Comment: try adding an `echo $SQL;` just before the `mysqli_query` command: what query is being executed? If you run that against your DBMS, do you get the correct results back?

Comment: Here's what's being run: SELECT * FROM minimodtable WHERE projectcode = '' OR projectname = 'CSAT Support' OR budget = '' OR startdate = '' OR enddate = '' OR cyear = '' OR cqtr = '' OR cgrp = '' OR sponsor = '' OR client = '' OR projectlead = '' OR originalhrs = '' OR riskpercent = '' OR notes = ''   It's bringing up the correct search, but also the rows with empty fields as well.

Comment: Are you passing the query parameters as empty strings as well, i.e. `myscript.php?projectcode=&projectname=CSAT%20Support&budget=&startdate=`...etc ? If so, that won't work! Omit them if you're not using them. If you cannot do that, then change the line with `if (isset($_GET[$param])) {` to `if (isset($_GET[$param]) && !empty(trim($_GET[$param]))) {`.

Comment: I believe they are being passed as empty strings, and I don't think I can omit them as at times I will need information from some of the columns, but also some of them will be empty. When I run your new (isset) line, I get this error: Can't use function return value in write context in /home/a4169484/public_html/minimod/retrieve1.php on line 29. I REALLY appreciate your help with this. If there is any "karma" I can send your way, just let me know!!!

Comment: oops :-) - remove the `trim()` part of that, so it becomes: `if (isset($_GET[$param]) && !empty($_GET[$param])) {`

Comment: HOLY COW YOU ARE A GENIUS!!!! Now, I have to spend the next few weeks trying to figure out what you just did!!!! Thank you so much.

Comment: If you are still following this thread, I would love to know how I would edit this (which works brilliantly) to be able to handle wildcard searches. I want to be able to search for things that aren't specifically/exactly in the database. In other words query 'park' to get everything like PARKER, PARKING, PARKED...etc